# time to date converstion

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

in our database, we have a column called ctime containing datetime in this format '1408097567'

I'd like to know how to convert this to date format like 'mm/yy/dd' using mysql or php

thank you very much I appreciate your help

Comment: `mm/yy/dd` year in the middle? never seen that one before

Comment: this is the client's requirements I don't know why he wants it though. ans I clarified the format that he wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the format is a **UNIX Timestamp** you can use **php**'s `date` function:

```
$time = '1408097567';
$time = date('M/Y/d', $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(ctime) as ctime
FROM your_table
```

If you need a specific date format use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) too.

Comment: This isn't converting the date to the specified format

Comment: It does, to the default format which is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: But OP wants **mm/yy/dd**

Comment: I interpreted as a date format **like** 'mm/yy/dd'.

Comment: I gave you voted this up because it partially answered my question. I can format it using php though. I chose @CarlMarkham's answer though :) thanks